# UIWebView load local html

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I have the basic app working fine when doing this, except for some reason my app is just outside of the screen? Does any one know why this would be?

[image]
My index page is just basic HTML, linked to a CSS Stylesheet..
and the Xcode:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    // Load the url into the webview
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("home", withExtension: "html");
        let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!);
        webView.loadRequest(myRequest);
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your code for this task? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to post it because it's quite a lot? This is my index page,

Comment: did you set auto layout at the storyboard?

Comment: I don't think so, how do you do that?!

Comment: @JessicaFryer select the UIWebView, hold down the right mouse and drag to up/down/left/right. You can find a tutorial on YouTube

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to do it or you have any issue this is the easy way if you have just only your `UIWebView`:

[image]